# Fill Drop down with jquery and set selected from .NET SelectList

Tags: .net, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a service that returns a object that contains .NET SelectList (both list and selected). With Jquery I have manage to fill the dropdown but I do not know how to set the correct selected value?

This is how the jquery code looks like :

```
                    success: function (data) {
                        methods.reset();
                        $.each(data, function () {
                            $this.append($(optionTag)
                                .attr("value", this.Value)
                                .text(this.Text));
                        });
```

I am setting the value and text but I do not se how to extract the selected value and set it on the dropdown object?

Pleas Advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Selected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem.selected.aspx) property:

```
$.each(data, function () {
    var option = $('<option/>').val(this.Value).text(this.Text);
    if (this.Selected) {
        option.attr('selected', 'selected');
    }
    $this.append(option);
});
```